# What is this es6 syntax called?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am relatively new to es6. I came across the following syntax and can't figure out what is it called.

```
let parameter = 'key1'; 
const obj = {
    'key1': 'value1',
    'key2': 'value2',
    'key3': 'value3',
  }[parameter];
```

Comment: Which line do you want a name for? :-)

Comment: Access object property via [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That concept is not specific to ES6.

That's just an object, out of which you're getting 1 value, depending on the `parameter`.

It is similar to:

```
let parameter = 'key1'; 
const temp = {
    'key1': 'value1',
    'key2': 'value2',
    'key3': 'value3',
}
const obj = temp[parameter];
```

Except `temp` is never declared.

Comment: Do you know what is this concept called?

Comment: Well it's ES6, but also valid plain old JavaScript. (except the const keyword)

Comment: I don't know of a specific name for this concept.

Comment: "Inline-accessing-an-object's-property"…?

Comment: "Shorthand substitute for a `switch`"…? (SSS)

Comment: Actually: "inline mapping a value to another value"?

Comment: I can't really find any documentation on this concept... That said, @mariazahid, did this answer your question?

Comment: @Cerbrus Thanks a lot. It did answer my question.

Comment: No problem :-) Please consider [accepting the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), @mariazahid

Answer (score 0):

Statement 1: **variable declaration** and definition.

Statement 2: variable declaration, **inline object definition** and accessing it using an **indexer**.

**FYI:** your code is plain old JavaScript. Only the `const` and `let` keywords are ECMAScript 6.

Comment: ES6 is “standard JavaScript” as well.

Comment: @FelixKling: Yes and no. It depends on what you understand by saying "standard".

Comment: Right. But you haven’t explained what you mean by it ;) or maybe I misinterpreted the statement in your answer.